# How do I extend a configuration form without using hook_form_alter()?

Tags: forms, 8

I want to extend some fields in a config form of a module with another module in Drupal 8. I created a config form in a module (e.g. custom_1) and now I want to add some more fields from another module (e.g. custom_2). custom_1 has a dependency on custom_2. I tried `hook_form_alter()` but it didn't resolve the issue.

Is there any other way to achieve this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

I came out to this solution:

I created a custom_1.routing.yml file and write the following code in it.

```
#Router settings for custom service page
custom_form.service_config:
path: '/admin/config/services/custom'
defaults:
  _form: '\Drupal\custom_1\Form\CustomConfigForm'
  _title: 'Custom Config Form'
  _description: 'Custom Configuration form.'
requirements:
  _permission: 'administer custom'
```

I created a CustomConfigForm.php file in custom_1/src/Form/CustomConfigForm.php.

```
    namespace Drupal\custom_1\Form;

    use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

    class CustomConfigForm extends ConfigFormBase {
      public funtion getFormId() {
          return 'custom_form_service_config_form'; 
      }
      public function getEditableConfigNames() {
          return ['custom_form.service_config'];  
      }
      public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
          // Form code here
         return buildform($form, $form_state);
      }
      public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
         // Submit code here
      }
    }
```

Now, I have to merge some more form fields from another module custom_2. To achieve this, I followed the following steps.
I created a custom_2.routing.yml file and write the following code in it.

```
#Router settings for custom service page
custom_form.service_config:
path: '/admin/config/services/custom'
defaults:
  _form: '\Drupal\custom_2\Form\CustomTwoConfigForm'
  _title: 'Custom Config Form'
  _description: 'Custom Configuration form.'
requirements:
  _permission: 'administer custom'
```

I created a CustomTwoConfigForm.php file in custom_2/src/Form/CustomTwoConfigForm.php.

```
    namespace Drupal\custom_2\Form;

    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
    use Drupal\custom_1\Form\CustomConfigForm;

    class CustomTwoConfigForm extends CustomConfigForm  {
      public funtion getFormId(){
          return 'custom_form_service_config_form'; 
      }
      public function getEditableConfigNames(){
          return ['custom_form.service_config'];  
      }
      public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
           $form = parent::buildform($form, $form_state);
          // Form code here
         return parent::buildform($form, $form_state);
      }
      public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
         // Submit code here
      }
    }
```

This resolve the issue for me without using `hook_form_alter()`.

Thanks

Comment: I would honestly advise you to use hook_form_alter until it has been officially deprecated in favor of a cleaner method. Why did hook_form_alter not work? Also, I am not sure you want to call parent::buildForm twice on $form, only once. The buildFrom method should be named buildForm, or is it intentionally buildFrom? The naming is confusing because its easily read as buildForm (used a lot in D8). This is why hook_form_alter for editing existing forms is still a cleaner option.

Comment: @Kevin:  In the above code parent::buildForm called twice in custom_2 module because the first parent::bulidFrom will get all the fields from custom_1 module and the second return the current form. I have been facing problem in saving fields during form submission when used hook_form_alter. As drupal 8 is using symfony architecture, that is the other reason why I used this approach instead of  hook_form_alter.

Comment: It just doesn't look maintainable and in the end does the same thing hook_form_alter would do. Add some fields, and add validate/submit handlers, and call them. Until core provides a way to form alter that is more in line with the OOP parts of Form API, I would keep it simple.